# How to get Spring MVC output using XStream to convert JSON to XML

Tags: xml, json, rest, spring-mvc, jettison

I have a web application using `Spring MVC (3.0.5)` that outputs `JSON` using the `HttpMessageConverter` when the `application/json` is passed in Accept header. I want to output `XML` using `XStream`, but instead of the underlying Java object, I want to use the `JSON` representation that I've already customized.

My spring configuration looks like

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="messageConverters">
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter" />
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter" />
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.SourceHttpMessageConverter" />
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

I can add another `XStreamMashaller` and get the `XML` output from the Java Object, but that's a different representation and I don't want to make the effort in syncing the two representations. I want to use the `JSON` representation to be converted to `XML` using something like `Jettison`. Can somebody guide me to a link or some example code on how this can be achieved?